# Fit automatictly the width of listbox's child

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, groupbox

I have a GroupBox in a Listbox and the GroupBox's width automaticly fit it's content. I want to fit the ListBox's width (even if resized) and never have any Scrollbar.

Here is  my XAML :

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox_1">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GroupBox Header="{Binding Name}" Margin="5">
                <!--DATA-->
            </GroupBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I have tried to set set the HorizontalAlignment's property of the GroupBox, but there is no effect.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Grid or stackPanel within GroupBox for display data.and set Grid Height and Width dynamically `auto` or `*`.and set ListBox ItemTemplate Propery `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"`